# how to share javascript code between front- and back-end (ES6)

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, dry, es6-modules

This is an ES6-specific duplicate of [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225251/how-can-i-share-code-between-node-js-and-the-browser), which details how to create a javascript module that can be exported for use in both a browser and node context.

I would be just as glad for an answer to appear there, if that's more appropriate.

For background, here's a quote of the ES5 solution, as well as the problems that arise in trying to translate it to ES6.  (Credit to users @caolan and @broesch.)

```
(function(exports){

    // Your code goes here. For example: 
   exports.test = function(){
        return 'hello world'
    };

})(typeof exports === 'undefined'? this.mymodule = {} : exports);
```

Thus, if `exports` is undefined, you must be in the browser, in which case `mymodule` is declared on the `window` (i.e., `this`).  Or, if `exports` is defined, it's in a `node` context, in which case you can just `var mymodule = require('mymodule')`.  And in either environment, you can then use it as `mymodule.test()`.  Great.

One problem with this is that `exports.whatever` doesn't expose `whatever` in the current scope, so if you want to use `whatever` within the module, you end up needing to do

```
var whatever = 3;
exports.whatever = whatever;
```

which can get cumbersome, and is easy to forget.

In ES6, on the other hand, you can do `export const whatever = 3`, which would both export and expose `whatever`, which is DRYer and thus easier to maintain.

The new problems are that

1. `export` must be at the top level of the file, which means you can't use the syntax from the ES5 answer
2. `export` isn't a function (is it?), so you can't use `type of` to achieve the conditional browser/node context.

So, my question is: what is the ES6 version of creating a `.js` file that can exported to both the browser and node?

Comment: "*what is the ES6 version of creating a .js file that can exported to both the browser and node?*" it's just a module that you can [use in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53023279/javascript-how-to-make-es6-imports-work-in-browser) and in Node?

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks for the reference.  But you can't write `import * from myFrontBackSharedFile as mymodule` in the browser context, so can you clarify the syntax to reference/namespace the module in the browser code?

Comment: [You should be able to use `import` in the browser](https://www.sitepoint.com/using-es-modules/)

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: There are many many different ways to accomplish this. It depends on your toolchain and the browsers you support

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I share code between Node.js and the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3225251/how-can-i-share-code-between-node-js-and-the-browser)